# How to generate PDF file of images in Android application programatically?

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate PDF of multiple images. I have used iText and droidText to do so but the generated pdf has poor quality of images. Can anybody please assist me here to generate pdf file of images having good resolution and quality.

Answer (score 0):

Use Foxit PDF Creator apk . which converts the image file to JPG, BMP, PNG, GIF, TIF, TXT,TIFF, RTF, and JPEG. and other formats . 
Advantages-
This app with a clean interface is simple to use.
Most file formats are supported to convert to PDF.
The PDF documents created are of high quality.
Disadvantages-
It will crash sometimes.
You need to buy the paid version.
Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxit.pdfcreator&hl=en

Comment: I need to create PDF file programatically. This will not work for me

Comment: programatically means in what way can you please hint me...!

Comment: it means I want to generate the PDF using code within my application. not by using another application